# Gzip compression of static files on google cloud storage breaks site

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gzip, gsutil, static-site

I host my static site on google cloud storage.

My files without gzip compression make my site work perfectly.

When I gzip my files locally (with `gzip -r folder`) prior to upload to my cloud storage bucket and run following command, my whole site breaks (images, js, css, all broken - no style information found warning etc.)

`gsutil -m -h content-encoding:gzip rsync -c -r ~/my-gzipped-folder gs://example.com`

Why the error and how to fix?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then `decompressive transcoding` is enabled somehow and that causes my site to break. To prevent/disable the transcoding I used `gsutil setmeta -h cache-control:no-transform gs://example.com/*` (right after my above `rsync` code with the `content-encoding:gzip`) but the `setmeta` command did not work, it did nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to your question may be lying [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#decompressive_transcoding).

> There are two ways to prevent decompressive transcoding from
>   occurring:
>
> If the request for the object includes an Accept-Encoding: gzip
>   header, the object is served as-is in that specific request, along
>   with a Content-Encoding: gzip response header.
>
> If the Cache-Control metadata field for the object is set to
>   no-transform, the object is served as a compressed object in all
>   subsequent requests, regardless of any Accept-Encoding request
>   headers.

Answer (score 2):

Seems I just had to upload my gzipped files without the `.gz` extension and then all good.